# Como posicionar elementos impares con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive

Hola a todos estoy trabajando con html, css y boostrap aca esta el codigo https://github.com/felipedelosh/ecomerceFuneraria y tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo 7 elementos en un row:

```
<div class="mainSolutionIcons">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionMovil">
                                <img src="img/ico/movil.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Movil</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionPos">
                                <img src="img/ico/pos.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>POS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionEtiquetas">
                                <img src="img/ico/etiquetas.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Etiquetas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSinRevestimiento">
                                <img src="img/ico/sin-revestimiento.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Sin revestimiento</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionKioscos">
                                <img src="img/ico/kioscos.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Kioscos</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSuministros">
                                <img src="img/ico/suministros.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Suministros</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSoftware">
                                <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Software</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image: Imagen original]

Cada imagen tiene un col-1 y el problema es que no se como centrar esos elementos.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
->Como centrar esos elementos si son impares?

Aquí les dejo un phoshopeado de lo que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola para centrar este tipo de figuras, utiliza flex. Flex es un modelo de css que incorporó Boostrap 4 y que es excelente para hacer estos posicionamientos.

En tu caso agregá al rox inicial la secuencia "justify-content-center" y el código centrará todos los iconos. El nuevo código quedaría así

```
<div class="mainSolutionIcons">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionMovil">
                                <img src="img/ico/movil.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Movil</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionPos">
                                <img src="img/ico/pos.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>POS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionEtiquetas">
                                <img src="img/ico/etiquetas.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Etiquetas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSinRevestimiento">
                                <img src="img/ico/sin-revestimiento.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Sin revestimiento</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionKioscos">
                                <img src="img/ico/kioscos.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Kioscos</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSuministros">
                                <img src="img/ico/suministros.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Suministros</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSoftware">
                                <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Software</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Explicación y datos**

En este link podes encontrar la explicacion de los diferentes comandos que soporta BS4 para flexbox: [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#justify-content)
Que es lo que hace este comando que agregamos? crea un bloque con todo lo que engloba el row y lo centra de manera justificada. Si cambias el comando podes justificar a derecha, a izquierda e incluso poner espacios entre iconos para que queden columnas equidistantes (probá justify-content-between y justify-content-around y fijate como queda).

Una pagina que me dío mucho resultado para entender flexbox es https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-basics

Ojala esta info sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigoooooo me funciono a la perfeción :)